# How to fetch the column names for the query

Tags: mysql, pdo

In this project, I have a dynamic columns which I stored in mapping table. Now usnig following query, I can fetch all the column names I need.

```
$db = new PDO("...");
$statement = $db->prepare("select column_name from mapping_table");
$list = $statement->fetch();
$matches = implode(',', $list);
```

Now from this result, I need to make a query. My question is how can I pass this $matches to the column_name of second query.

```
$db1 = new PDO("...");
$qry1= $db1->prepare("select {$matches} from table1");
$result= $qry1->fetch();
```

Comment: What happens if you just use: `("select $matches from table1")`?

Comment: No it is not giving me result saying as unknown column $matches

Comment: I've given an example, please let me know if it works for you..

Comment: Updated example with using `fetchAll()` instead since its only the first column you require, and all results are wanted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
db = new PDO("...");
$statement = $db->query("select column_name from mapping_table");
$list = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
$matches = implode('`,`', $list);
```

And then:

```
$db1 = new PDO("...");
$qry1= $db1->query("select `$matches` from table1");
$result= $qry1->fetch();
```

Comment: now it worked. Before when I did same it was not working. I dont know what had happen before. Anyways Thank you

Comment: Good to hear it worked for you. Was it the first example or after the last edit with `fetchAll()` that worked for you?

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Your Common Sence.. realised the array_keys where not needed when using fetchAll()...

Comment: there are a lot more things you didn't realize as well

Comment: Enlighten me :-), missed the back ticks. I just try to give fast answers to try earning some reputation, missing things in all haste sometimes..